# tooltip issue in raphael js for area graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, prototypejs, raphael

I need to generate tool tip on area graph using Raphael.js. But tool tip has be shown on hover at particular x,y coordinates only( position is important since it is a multi area graph).
I am able to generate this area graph and tool-tip as well.
There are multiple lines on tool tip and each should have separate styling and not same styling.

I am unable to rotate the tooltip by 90 degree and there is a problem since the tool-tip keeps shifting downwards when text size changes. 
So are there any way where can style each text on each line differently and keep the tool-tip at correct place?

Comment: can you show a jsfiddle or jsbin of the problem ?

Comment: I am using the implementation available at this GIT repo  https://github.com/kilian/grafico  . The code samples available in this repository are self sufficient to create many graphs. How ever I have modified some of the code related to tool tip and the colors for stacked area graph. But I am not able to get the desired result for tool-tip customization on the stacked area graph. So any clue on that. I tried to put this on jsbin but I am unable find the library for grafico js. these js's are not hosted on any site

Comment: The sample graph is hosted on this URL http://grafico.kilianvalkhof.com/documentation/index.html#stack ( please check the second graph with tool tip under stacked area graphs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved.
Since Grafico was really tough to customize I used Jquery FLOT library for my requirement .
I am able to do any  required customization in FLOT and FLOT is very fast and easy to use with so much support available on the FLOT site.